# Load Image using RxJava into Google map setInfoWindowAdapter

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap, android-imageview, rx-java

Hello I have an imageview that sets its image with a bitmap image obtained using a Single inside a google map but unfortunately the image will not load. I read some solution that use the callback feature from picasso but for this function I am just using a regular Imageview.setImageBitmap. I have tried hiding and showing the marker but I had not luck. Thank you for your help!

JAVA:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {


 ......

this.googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

.....

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(final Marker marker) {

final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);

Single<Bitmap> imageSingle = getImageWithURL(url);     

        imageSingle.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())     

        .subscribe(new SingleSubscriber<Bitmap>() {     

    @Override     

    public void onSuccess(Bitmap image) {     

        Log.e(TAG, "" + image.getWidth());     

        Log.e(TAG, images.size() + "");     

        imageView.setImageBitmap(image); //this line doesnt work     

        Log.e(TAG, "Sucess");     
             
    }          

    @Override     

    public void onError(Throwable error) {     

        Log.e(“Image”, error.tostring())     

    }     
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out this issue after a lot of digging! The issue is that the marker loads and converts the view into an image, and since my Single adds the image after it has been converted it wont display. To fix this all you gotta do is load the images before hand and then inside the marker just call the imageview.set function. Hope this helps to anybody that has this issue!